# Latest gcm-server jar file with option to set priority for notifications

Tags: java, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

With respect to GCM, google has introduced a new property which allows the server side to set priority for the notifications.

```
com.google.android.gcm.server.Message message = new    
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Message.Builder(). 
timeToLive(180).delayWhileIdle(true).addData("message",messageToSend).build();
```

Similarly we should be able to set priority and build the message.
I am not able to get an option to set priority in the jar file which is available i.e

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gcm</groupId>
    <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help me with the latest jar file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently that library does not support message priority, however it will be added soon. If you must have priority now your best option is to clone the [latest version](https://github.com/google/gcm) and build it yourself.